# Printing Kafka KTable, KStream and KGroupedStream values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Java how can I print the content of Kafka `KTable`, `KStream` and `KGroupedStream` ? I don't see any implicit method for this.

Comment: There is indeed a `print` method. You can convert tables to streams to use it too https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#print-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed-

Comment: Can you please give one example

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting, but as the Javadoc shows, you can `stream.print(Printed.toSysout())`... Or `table.toStream().print(...)`

Comment: how can I print the value of `KGroupedStream`?

Comment: Use one of its methods to make it a table, then `toStream().print()` like I said before